# Having trouble displaying object property

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, svelte

I'm building a small pokedex using PokeAPI. I'm retrieving data from an endpoint and building my own object. The function that I've built for the latter runs on page load as follows:

```
$: pokemon = []

//fetch pokemon from PokeAPI

function getPokemon(){
let index = 0

fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151") //
    .then(response => response.json()) //
    .then(allpokemon =>  {
    allpokemon.results.map((poke) => 
    
        pokemon = [...pokemon, {
            index: index++,
            name: poke.name
        }]
    )})
}   


//populate pokemon array on page load
getPokemon()
```

I'm able to console log the object and traverse it in devtools, and also able to JSON stringify it and display within html. But whenever I try to retrieve a specific attribute, I receive a 500 error. For instance, **I'm trying to display the current pokemons name in an h1 tag** :

```
<h1>{pokemon[currentPokemon].name</h1> // this doesn't work
```

whereas

```
<h1>{pokemon[currentPokemon]</h1> //this does
```

This can't be too complicated of a fix, I just don't know what I'm missing, because I've been traversing objects for what I thought was the correct way for years now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is missing a curly brace at the end

```
<h1>{pokemon[currentPokemon].name</h1>
```

Besides that `pokemon` will initially be an empty array, so independent of `currentPokemon` the value will be `undefined` and accessing the key `name` will give the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')` which could be solved by adding a questionmark [(Optional chaining)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
<h1>{pokemon[currentPokemon]?.name}</h1>
```

There's no need for the `$:`, just `let pokemon = []`
`.map()` returns an array, so instead of setting `pokemon` inside the function better assign it the result. The index would be available as second parameter inside `.map()`

```js
.then(allpokemon =>  {
            pokemon = allpokemon.results.map((poke, index) => {
                return {
                    name: poke.name, // or ...poke, to keep all fields
                    index
                }
            })
```

Writing the index in the data might not be neccessary if an `#each` loop is used to display the data

```html
{#each pokemon as p, index}
    <p>
        {index} - {p.name}
    </p>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<h1>{pokemon[currentPokemon]['name']}</h1>
```

Comment: I tried that method already. in error message, name is undefined. I tried with/without quotes. conversely if you just try to display pokemon[currentPokemon].. you still get the whole object

Comment: Have u tried closing the curly braces '}'. Also if u r coding in angular it should be
<h1>{{pokemon[currentPokemon]['name']}}</h1>

Comment: This is svelte. output is just javascript within one pair of curly braces.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).